# tikxml No TypeAdapter

Tags: java, android, tikxml

build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:annotation:0.8.13'
    implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:core:0.8.13'
    implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:retrofit-converter:0.8.13'
```

docs.class

```
@Xml(name = "docs")
public class docs {
    @Attribute(name = "docs")
    public ArrayList<doc> doc = new ArrayList <>();

}
```

doc.class

```
public class doc {
    @PropertyElement(name="bookname")
    String bookname;
    @PropertyElement(name="authors")
    String authors;
    @PropertyElement(name="isbn13")
    String isbn13;
    @PropertyElement(name="bookImageURL")
    String bookImageURL;
    public doc(){

    }
    public doc(String title, String authors, String isbn13, String bookImageURL) {
        this.bookname = title;
        this.authors = authors;
        this.isbn13 = isbn13;
        this.bookImageURL = bookImageURL;


    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return bookname;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.bookname = title;
    }
    public String getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }
    public void setAuthors(String authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }
    public String getIsbn13() {
        return isbn13;
    }
    public void setIsbn13(String isbn13) {
        this.isbn13 = isbn13;
    }
    public String getBookImageURL() {
        return bookImageURL;
    }
    public void setBookImageURL(String bookImageURL) {
        this.bookImageURL = bookImageURL;
    }



}
```

main.class

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://data4library.kr/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(TikXmlConverterFactory.create(tikXml))
                .build();

        Library retable = retrofit.create(Library.class);
        Call <docs> call = retable.getRes("key","2021-04-11");
        Log.d("request", call.request().toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback <docs>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <docs> call, Response <docs> response) {

                Log.d("Title", livo.get(0).getTitle());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call <docs> call, Throwable t) {
         
                Log.d("Test", t.getMessage());
            }
        });


public interface Library {
    @GET("loanItemSrch")
    Call<docs> getRes(
            @Query("authKey") String authKey,
            @Query("startDt") String startDt

    );
}
```

[image]

XML parsing using retrofit

You get an error that you can't solve on your own.

No TypeAdapKter for class

When the log was received with call.request(), the address was normally

I'm connected, but the onFailure() method keeps showing me an error message

I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've also added the `annotationProcessor` in your gradle file:
`annotationProcessor 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:processor:0.8.13'`

Comment: nothing happens after using it.

Comment: I got TypeAdapter generated after addind these two

'com.github.Tickaroo.tikxml:processor-common:0.8.15'
'com.github.Tickaroo.tikxml:processor:0.8.15'